# Have six of the ten 9/11 commission members said that the US government was covering up something about the 9/11 attacks?

Tags: united-states, 9-11, terrorism

I often see claims like this repeated, *"six out of the Ten 9/11 Comission members have gone on record since to admit there was a U.S. government cover-up."* Any truth to it? This last time I saw it was on this [Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151072659151446&set=a.10150891164271446.416309.190824176445&type=1) by [Conspiracy Theory with Jesse Ventura on truTV](https://www.facebook.com/ConspiracyTheoryWithJesseVentura). The page has 209,000 followers as of September 11, 2012.

[image: 9/11 truther propaganda.]

I believe this claim is rooted [in this webpage.](http://beyondleftright.com/topics/september-11/1495-6-of-10-911-commissioners-say-qofficial-storyq-a-lie)

Comment: What exactly are these claims saying is being 'covered up'?

Comment: Does it matter? Do 6 of the 10 say *anything* was covered up?

Comment: The [full 9/11 report is available](http://www.9-11commission.gov/report/911Report.pdf) online (PDF) and the commission members are Thomas H. Kean, Lee H. Hamilton, Richard Ben-Veniste, Bob Kerrey, Fred F. Fielding, John F. Lehman, Jamie S. Gorelick, Timothy J. Roemer, Slade Gorton and James R.Thompson

Comment: There is no claim that the member withdrew their findings.  It could be that there is a coverup of something that did not impact their findings or that was disclosed in their findings.

Answer (score 19):

**No.**

There was one commission member, Max Cleland, who ["blasted" the White House](http://www.democracynow.org/2004/3/23/the_white_house_has_played_cover) and claimed a cover up. He withdrew as a commission member and was replaced by Bob Kerrey.

Aside from Max, I can find no evidence of any of the other members "going on record" to admit a government cover-up.

The [full 9/11 report is available online](http://www.9-11commission.gov/report/911Report.pdf) (PDF) and the commission members are Thomas H. Kean, Lee H. Hamilton, Richard Ben-Veniste, Bob Kerrey, Fred F. Fielding, John F. Lehman, Jamie S. Gorelick, Timothy J. Roemer, Slade Gorton and James R.Thompson.

Comment: I updated the question with the source I believe is used to substantiate this claim.