# Was 9-11 planned by the US Government?

Tags: united-states, 9-11

One of my friend told me about [this site](http://investigate911.org/). It gives many proofs related to the catastrophic event. The use of Nano-thermite strongly suggests that the buildings were imploded.
Although I do not trust these kinda sites, but presence of a conspiracy can't be completely rejected. Was it really pre-planned by USA itself?

> **Related questions:**
>
> - [On 9/11, was Building 7 destroyed in a controlled explosion?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1368/on-911-was-building-7-destroyed-in-a-controlled-explosion)
> - [Did the U.S. government have prior knowledge of 9/11?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2076/did-the-u-s-government-have-prior-knowledge-of-9-11)
> - [Have six of the ten 9/11 commission members said that the US government was covering up something about the 9/11 attacks?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10862/have-six-of-the-ten-9-11-commission-members-said-that-the-us-government-was-cove)
> - [Was Osama Bin Laden responsible for 9-11?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2971/was-osama-bin-laden-responsible-for-9-11)

Comment: I'm hating myself for voting to reopen, but "Was it a false-flag operation?" is not a duplicate of "Was this a controlled implosion?" (OTOH, "was it false-flag?" may be un-falsifiable.)

Comment: @LarryOBrien: Fair point - there are several claims here, and I have added related questions to demonstrate we have covered each of them - who was responsible, the idea of prior knowledge, the idea the buildings were imploded.

Comment: "presence of a conspiracy can't be completely rejected" - well, often it can ("That which can be asserted without evidence, can be dismissed without evidence." - Christopher Hitchens,) but in the case of 9-11, it cannot. The evidence points directly towards a horrific conspiracy involving at least [26 people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijackers_in_the_September_11_attacks).